# How to keep sidebar layout fixed, not scrollable with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a simple admin panel. I added a sidebar as layout. I want to keep it fixed. But when I scroll down the page my sidebar also scrolls down. Here is how it looks at the beginning of page:

[image]

And when I scroll down the page:

[image]

I want to keep it as in picture 1 even the page is scrolled down. The beginning of siderbar is like this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar" style="max-height:100%">
```

Edit: I tried `.navbar-nav { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0, width: 150px; }` and result is:
[image]

Comment: .navbar-nav { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0, width: 150px; } ???

Comment: When I try that, my page came on top of sidebar.  I edited question and added a screenshot.

Comment: usually, you have content container div. side by side with navbar. in the content, have padding-left (same as navbar width).

Comment: Yes, I added position-fixed and gave margin-left to content div. It solved. I will accept yours as answer if you want to write it.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo but I have a new problem. It's not responsive now. When I shrink the page, bottom of my sidebar just not visible. I cant click the buttons on bottom and can't scroll it as well.

Comment: are you using one of the library or it is created your own? it is difficult to say when i don't see. yes, the solution i gave is not responsive.

Comment: I took it from sb-admin2 and just changed the items. It's a ready bootstrap theme.

Comment: @media (min-width: 768px)
.sidebar {
    width: 14rem!important;
    position: fixed;
}

#content-wrapper {
padding-left: 225px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 px-1 bg-dark position-fixed">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <h1>Main Area</h1>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if I made it correct but that caused too much chaos on page. It solved with position-fixed and margin. Thank you.